# Get reference to T inside Option<T> when .as_ref() changes type

Tags: rust

I have an `Option<Url>` (rust-url).  I want to get a reference to the inner Url or another value.  Intuitively I wrote:

```rust
// backup_value: &Url
let url = optional_url.map(|url| url.as_ref()).unwrap_or(backup_value);
```

Unfortunately `AsRef` is implemented [for string](https://docs.rs/url/2.5.0/url/struct.Url.html#impl-AsRef%3Cstr%3E-for-Url) on this type (i.e. it returns an `&str`) so this attempts to assign two different types to `url` and doesn't compile.  Likewise this is obviously impossible:

```rust
let url = optional_url.map(|url| &url).unwrap_or(backup_value);
```

as is this:

```rust
let url = match optional_url {
    Some(url) => &url,
    None => backup_url,
}
```

Since the value goes out of scope before the borrow.  I can give in and clone `backup_url` to own it:

```rust
let url = match(optional_url) {
    Some(url) => url,
    None => backup_url.clone(),
};
// later on
some_fn(&url);
```

But this feels ugly: I only need an `&Url`, and `backup_url` is an `&Url` passed to the function.  I'm cloning here only to borrow immediately.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `optional_url.as_ref().unwrap_or(backup_value)`, ([it's signature is `&Option<T> -> Option<&T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref)) will work, the equivalent match statement can do it, too, the trick is to take the reference before matching (or using `ref`):

```rust
let url = match &optional_url {
    Some(url) => url,
    None => backup_url,
}
```

or

```rust
let url = match optional_url {
    Some(ref url) => url,
    None => backup_url,
}
```